# Dispatching CustomEvent always returns true

Tags: javascript, dom-events

According to (my understanding of the) [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent), the `dispatchEvent` method should return `false` if any of the event listeners is calling `Event.preventDefault()` method while processing it.
But if I try that with a `CustomEvent` object, `dispatchEvent` always returns `true`. Please check the following snippet out:

```js
var div = document.getElementById("test");

div.addEventListener("custom", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});

div.innerHTML = div.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("custom"));
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're dispatching a custom event called 'test' but listening for 'custom', so your handler is never called.  You also need to ensure your event is cancellable by adding `cancelable: true` to the init object:

```js
var div = document.getElementById("test");

div.addEventListener("custom", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});

div.innerHTML = div.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("custom", {
    cancelable: true
}));
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! ..yes sorry in my real case events have the same name, but it was returning true anyway. The key is `cancelable: true`! :)